# How can I change the dates used in TFS 2010 SharePoint portal's burndown excel chart?

Tags: tfs2010, excel

We have a TFS 2010 project (MSF Agile v5.0 template) project, the SSRS reports for burndown allow us to specify start and end dates for the current iteration, but the project portals excel charts parts for burndown do not seem to have that option anywhere I can find it.

[image: An example Excel burndown chart with incorrect itteration dates]

Can anyone explain how I can configure the portal's excel burndown chart to have the begin and end dates **I want** rather than the defaults?

Comment: This is more ALM (and for that matter TFS 2010) that pure test but I am reposting here as the area 51 prop was closed as a duplicate of this site; which I take to mean its the preferred place for ALM issues in the large rather than pure test questions.  The repost here is in the hope of a more apropriate audience!

Comment: thanks for the clarification on that. You're right it isn't exactly SQA material, although you could argue in the broader definition of SQA that any ALM practices fall under it.

Comment: Clarifying these features of TFS doesn't contribute to the body of SQA knowledge here.

Comment: Re TFS questions please see http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37/alm-questions-on-sqa in meta (voting to close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates for the burn down chart in excel for the Agile and CMMI templates are set by the date filters on the chart, you need to right click on the date column in the pivot table and then select the dates you want.

For the new agile template, these dates are probably sourced from the start and finish dates on the sprint work item template.